# Docker pull images from private repository and pulling changes on images

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I want to manage a docker private repository in order of pull images using insecure protocol (http), my question is: It is possible to pull changes on images when something changes on the image I have in the repository or I have to pull all the images again??

For example when something changes on the code that I have in the images in the repository and then I rebuild it on my server I would like to pull that changes from any pc... Something like git I mean

Thank you all!

Comment: Have you tested `docker commit`, `docker push`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tested docker commit or push because I know that is useful to save changes from container to images.. But I usually don't work on code inside the container.. When I make changes I usually rebuild my Dockerfile (my ADD commands are on the buttom in order to don't invalidate cache).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is possible to pull changes on images when something changes on the image I have in the repository or I have to pull all the images again?? For example when something changes on the code that I have in the images in the repository and then I rebuild it on my server I would like to pull that changes from any pc... Something like git I mean

You can't pull only the changes like `git`. Docker pulls images and this means that you will have to **run new containers after the image is updated**. As it is described here: [How to upgrade docker container after its image changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734402/how-to-upgrade-docker-container-after-its-image-changed), your workflow/setup should allow you to:

- `pull` the new image
- `stop` your running container
- `remove` it
- `run` it again with the new version

I think you should also do some research on `tags` which might help you. Since your are updating code, you can use images with different tags. I have found this question: [How to update a Docker Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25552038/how-to-update-a-docker-image) which has many useful things you may wanna use.

Also, if you are using the `:latest` tag, you should keep in mind the following:

> If you are shipping Docker images to a production environment, you should just ignore the `latest tag`. Don’t use it. Don’t be tempted by it. It’s easy to look at it and think that your deployment script should just pull “latest” and your build process will ensure that’s valid. It takes a lot of discipline to make that work. **Just version your tags. Every time.**

mentioned here: [The misunderstood Docker tag: latest](https://medium.com/@mccode/the-misunderstood-docker-tag-latest-af3babfd6375)

Comment: Thank you !! Just what I was looking for :)